# Too many quotation marks in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, quotation-marks

my problem is too many quotation marks.

```
$come = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="$_POST['email']" and password="$_POST['password']" ");
```

Then I tried this but it doesn't work ...

```
$come = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="/$_POST['email']/" and password="/$_POST['password']/" ");
```

Please help me :/

Comment: Use a modern DB interface and bind parameters. Anything else is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: As Mat says you should use bind parameters, but if you insist on doing it like you are (which contains a security hole) then you should be using single quotes for `WHERE email='some string'`, even if MySQL lets you use double quotes there. Then you'll probably need to use escaped double quotes for `$_POST[\"email\"]`. Also, you should learn the difference between a slash and a backslash :) and use them before the thing you're trying to escape.

Comment: And the difference between single and double quotes :-) which used in a nice way reduces the amount of scaping chars...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$come = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."' and password='".$_POST['password']."' ");
```

Try this it should fix your issue. But mysql is deprecated consider mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Apart from the sql injection problem, this will not work as string values need to be quoted in mysql.

Comment: Yop, thank you ... I forgot that there should be dots :) Thank you .. :)) #NewInMysql

Comment: I know there is sql injection danger and the method is deprecated but i  cant understand the downvotes. I suggested to change method but my answer answers OP question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your question:

```
<?php
$come = mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="%s" and password="%s"', $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']));
```

But you should never use code like this. You have a SQL Injection in your code. Rewrite this using `PDO`.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'password');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email and password=:password');
$stmt->execute(['email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $_POST['password']]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

More: 
http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Okay, I 'll check it .. This is my school project so they do not mind security flaws. Thank you :)